# UNDEFINED: Problemas con JSON y $.ajax en Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonobject, undefined

Tengo el siguiente codigo en Javascript que hace un GET a una API y me devuelve un JSON

```
function cargar(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  dataType: 'text',
  error : function(errorThrown,err,textStatus){
    console.log(textStatus)
    console.log(errorThrown)
    console.log(err)
  },
  success : function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) 
    console.log(json)
    console.log(json.root)
  }
 });
}
```

El JSON que me devuelve es el siguiente (está en github porque es muy grande): https://github.com/OCorleto/JSONCpu

El problema es que al imprimir

```
console.log(json)
```

me devuelve el JSON mostrado anteriormente, pero al imprimir

```
console.log(json.root)
```

me devulve

```
undefined
```

además de no poderlo recorrer con un ForEach.

INFO EXTRA:
Si **datatype** no es *text* me lanza un parseerror y el JSON.Parse(JSON.stringify(data)) no me devuelve ningún error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la petición indicas que el tipo de datos devuelto va a ser `text` y no json, por lo que la variable `data` va a contener una cadena con el json que muestras en tu enlace, en lugar del objeto resultante de parsearlo.

Luego, en lugar de parsear esa cadena a un objeto, en primer lugar haces un `JSON.stringify` del valor. `JSON.stringify` serializa un valor en formato json, mientras que `JSON.parse` lo deseraializa. Por lo que una operación deshace lo realizado por la otra.

Para obtener el valor devuelto como objeto te bastaría con deserializar la variable `data`:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Aunque lo mejor es que en la petición indiques que el valor devuelto va a ser en formato json:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

y de esta forma en la variable data ya tendrás el objeto deserializado sin necesidad de llamar `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Al cambiar el datatype a 'application/json' me devuelve el error  no conversion from texto to application/json eso será algún problema con lo que recibo del get?

Comment: Perdona, culpa mía. Esto me pasa por poner las cosas de memoria cuando hace tiempo que no utilizo jQuery para hacer consultas. El dataType debe ser 'json'. Corrijo la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, con json si me funcionó